# Javascript change name format from AD container

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the format of how a name displays when a distinguished name is in the format "CN=Doe\, John" to display as "John Doe". How can I change this code to account for it?

```js
function changeName(name) {
  if (name.startsWith("CN=")) {
    if (name.indexOf("CN=", 3) != -1) {
      name = name.substring(3, name.indexOf('CN=', 3) - 1);
    } else if (name.indexOf("OU=", 3) != -1) {
      name = name.substring(3, name.indexOf('OU=', 3) - 1);
    }
  } else if (name.startsWith("(null)")) {
    name = "";
  }
  
  return name;
}

console.log(changeName('CN=Doe, John'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like that. This assumes that names are always split with comma + space and there's equal sign.

```js
function changeName(name) {
  if (name.startsWith("CN=") || name.startsWith("OU=")) {
    const parts1 = name.split(', ');
    const parts2 = parts1[0].split('=');
    return `${parts1[1]} ${parts2[1]}`;
    
  } else if (name.startsWith("(null)")) {
    return '';
  }
  
  return null;
}

console.log(changeName('CN=Doe\, John'));
```

Reference: [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Not all names are listed in that way, but this is a good start.